# Why do we need to override the methods of parent class?

Tags: java

I mean if we want to rewrite all the content of the method in the child class and change its function, why couldn't we just write a new method with a different name?  What's the difference? I know this is a simple question. But I am new to programming and very confused. THX.

Comment: When you give a method the same signature as a parent you replace the functionality the parent would give with a new one.  If you give it another signature, it doesn't

Answer (score 1):

It's about giving different behaviour to common functionality for that type of thing, for example let's assume all Vehicles beep, but a Car Honk's and a Moped Meep Meeps!

```
class Vehicle {

   public void beep() {
       System.out.println("Beep!");
   }

}

class Car extends Vehicle {

   @Override
   public void beep() {
       System.out.println("Honk!");   
   }

}

class Moped extends Vehicle {

   @Override
   public void beep() {
       System.out.println("Meep Meep!");       
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's called [Polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_%28computer_science%29). Have a look at the link.

A simple example is the Java Collections framework. You have an interface `List` when you are using it. You don't want to know how `add` or `size` is working. It should just work.

But when you are on the implementation side there are differences for `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList` in the way how they manage the items, that where stored in there.

When you look at already implemented methods in super classes, you might need one method to have a different behavior. Now pretend you have some method calls in your current code. If you don't want them to change, so you just override that method and the client does not have to change his code in order to use your functionality.

Comment: This is not really overriding though. It is implementing. I guess deathlee is asking about overriding a method that has already been implemented in the superclass.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding is a feature that is available while using Inheritance.

It is used when a class that extends from another class wants to use most of the feature of the parent class and wants to implement specific functionality in certain cases.

```
class Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Animals can move");
   }
}

class Dog extends Animal{

   public void move(){
      System.out.println("Dogs can walk and run");
   }
}

class Cat extends Animal{

}

public class TestDog{

   public static void main(String args[]){
      Animal a = new Animal(); // Animal reference and object
      Animal b = new Dog(); // Animal reference but Dog object
      Animal c = new Cat(); // Animal reference but Cat object

      a.move();// runs the method in Animal class
      b.move();//Runs the method in Dog class
      c.move();//Runs the method super method
   }
}
```

So by using a parent class you dont need to define move() in each of class that extends animal you can override it wherever necessary.